# Is It possible to use query projection on the same collection that has a $elemMatch projection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I understand that you can limit the items in a subcollection array using [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) as a projection. When using it as such it returns all fields of the subdocuments that match regardless if [query projections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) are also specified.

Is it possible to limit the fields returned in the matching subdocuments? How would you do so?

*Using version 3.8.9.*

Given the simple schemas:

```
var CommentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  body: String,
  created: {
    by: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
  }
});

var BlogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  blog: String,
  created: {
    by: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
  },
  comments: [CommentSchema]
});

var Blog = mongoose.model('Blog',modelSchema);
```

**Example**

```
Blog.findOne({_id: id}, {_id: 1, comments: {$elemMatch: {'created.by': 'Jane'}, body: 1}}, function(err, blog) {
  console.log(blog.toJSON());
});
// outputs:
{
  _id: 532cb63e25e4ad524ba17102,
  comments: [
    _id: 53757456d9c99f00009cdb5b,
    body: 'My awesome comment',
    created: { by: 'Jane', date: Fri Mar 21 2014 20:34:45 GMT-0400 (EDT) }
  ]
}

// DESIRED OUTPUT
{
  _id: 532cb63e25e4ad524ba17102,
  comments: [
    body: 'My awesome comment'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are two ways to do this. So you can either use the [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) on the projection side as you already have, with slight changes:

```
Model.findById(id,
   { "comments": { "$elemMatch": {"created.by": "Jane" } } },
   function(err,doc) {
```

Or just add to the query portion and use the positional `$` operator:

```
Model.findOne(
    { "_id": id, "comments.created.by": "Jane" },
    { "comments.$": 1 },
    function(err,doc) {
```

Either way is perfectly valid.

If you wanted something a little more involved than that, you can use the [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method and it's [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator instead:

```
Model.aggregate([
    // Still match the document
    { "$match": "_id": id, "comments.created.by": "Jane" },

    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$comments" },

    // Only match elements, there can be more than 1
    { "$match": "_id": id, "comments.created.by": "Jane" },

    // Project only what you want
    { "$project": {
        "comments": {
            "body": "$comments.body",
            "by": "$comments.created.by"
        }
    }},

    // Group back each document with the array if you want to
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "comments": { "$push": "$comments" }
    }}
],
function(err,result) {
```

So the aggregation framework can be used for a lot more than simply aggregating results. It's [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator gives you more flexibility than is available to projection using `.find()`. It also allows you to filter and return multiple array results, which is also something that cannot be done with projection in `.find()`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I think I didn't emphasize my question well enough. I understand _how_ to filter the `comments` subcollection using both of those methods but I want to also use query projection on the same subcollection to **select which fields to return for each subdocument**. I've edited my original question to include a more obvious example of the desired output.

Comment: @JasonCust I don't see an edit in your question at this stage, but I think some variation of the `aggregate` example at the end there is what you are looking for, based on your comment.

Comment: Apologies. I thought I saved the update last night but apparently not. So this is just a limitation of projections in `.find()` with `$elemMatch`? I was looking into the aggregate method as well but was concerned if there is a heavy performance penalty over using `.find()`. I will check it out today. Thanks again.

Comment: @JasonCust the general limitation is that projections are fairly limited with `.find()` alone and while you can do something like `comments.body` and get all array members but just the body field, you cannot do `comments.$.body` just to get the one that matched. So the usage of `aggregate` does come with some additional cost as it is doing more things, but that should be fairly negligible unless your arrays are quite large. It is also the only way to get more than 1 match in the array elements.