# find subdocument in mongodb with specific id and username

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
 {
 _id:"101",
 title : "this is title",
 comments: 
 [{
    username : "mark zucker",
    comment: "awsome"
    }]

  }
```

i tried to get the comment with username "mark zucker" by this code below

```
 app.get('/all',function(req , res){
 db.collection.find({"_id":101},{"comments.username":'mark zucker'},function(err,docs){res.send(docs,{data:docs});});
 } );
```

but i get the output as

```
  {
  "data": [
    {
     "_id": 101,
     "comments": [
      {
        "user": "mark zucker"
      },
       {
        "user": "bella"
      }
    ]
    } 
 ]
  }
```

please help me to get only the particular comment with username :"mark zucker" .

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

Comment: Or just basic projection using the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator. `$elemMatch` should only be required when you require matching on more than one property of an array element. Both forms are demonstrated just a [few questions ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23692340/2313887)

Comment: if some one of you can explain it in answer portion i can approve it so it help me to close this question

Comment: @NeilLunn yeah it works fine with $elemMatch thank you

Comment: do u know how to update the document with _id:101 with comments username : mark zucker ? @NeilLunn

Comment: Updating is a different question, but the hint is looking at the form of the query as used in the second example in the answer I gave you a link to.